# [Python]pandas markdown doesn't show properly in slack channel

Tags: slack, slack-api

I collected the economic calendar from investpy and rearranged in markdown as below,

```
text=pd.DataFrame.to_markdown(data,tablefmt='simple')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM6gr.png)

### But while I transfer this markdown to Slack channel by code below,

```
response=client_slack.chat_postMessage(channel=channel_id,
                                       text=markdown)
```

---

it only shows like the below,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTUfH.png)

anyone knows why the layout doesn't show exactly from Jupyter lab?

Comment: Seems like Slack Markdown doesn't work well with whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Slack doesn't use Common Markdown, so doesn't have a notion of a markdown table. Instead it relies on a markdown-like syntax called `mrkdwn`, which is outlined [here](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#basics)